# Maximal Solution of ODE Bounded by a Positive Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{1+d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$ continuous such that $\|F(t,x)\|\leq g(\|x\|)$ for some function $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{g(s)}=\infty. \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
Prove that all maximum solution of $x'=F(t,x)$ with $x(t_0)=0$ are definite for all $t\geq t_0$.

I tried it this way:
By Picard Theorem, we can write the ODE solution as
$$\gamma(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t}F(s,\gamma(s))ds.$$
So, by hypothesis we have
$$\|\gamma(t)\|\leq\int_{t_0}^{t}g(\|\gamma(s)\|)ds.$$
From here, I didn't know how to continue. I've no idea how to use $(1)$.
Somebody can help me? Any hint? Thanks! :D

Comment: Have you tried to use that the graph of a maximal solution tends to the boundary of the open set which $F$ is defined when $t$ tends to one of the extrems of $\gamma$'s domain?